# Orbeon Forms: Read grid and section of a control

Tags: orbeon

How do I read the **grid** and **section** that a specific control sits in?

I need to use this information in an xPath formula to dynamically build up the formula string.

Many thanks

PeteA

Comment: I am not sure I understand. What do you mean by "dynamically build up the formula string"? Do you mean with an external tool, for from Form Builder?

Comment: Maybe an example of what you're trying to do would help.

Comment: To make it simpler - how do I read the the grid and section that a specific control sits in?

This will then feed into one of my other open questions regarding building up dynamic field names:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75603340/orbeon-forms-dynamically-reference-a-control-value

Comment: @PeteAtkin, there is no provision for getting the name of the grid or names of the sections that contain a given control.  This for a reason: control names have to be unique, so you can just refer to them by their name, and don't need to know the grid/sections names. Now, maybe you have a use case we haven't thought about where you do need to have those grid/sections names, but I can't tell without knowing more, and this is why I'm asking for the use case, if possible illustrated with an example. Does this make sense? -Alex

Comment: Alex,
Its the other way around, I want to know which grid and/or section that a specific control sits within (so from the perspective of the individual control)

Comment: Another thought..
Can we read the binding to determine the section or grid, or can we use the "Name of the PDF field" value in the control settings?

Comment: @PeteAtkin Does my comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/75608556/5295 answer this as well? -Alex

Comment: Sorry - unfortunately it doesnt answer the question..

Comment: @PeteAtkin Got it, so I gather that this is something different. As I understand the problem you described in the other question better, I would suggest that we tackle that one first. Have you tried the suggestion I have in my March 9 comment on that other question? I will let you follow up there when you get a chance, and we can then come back to this one ;). -Alex