# Orbeon Forms: Dynamically Reference a Control Value

Tags: orbeon

Depending on other control values we may need to get data from one of many sources (up to 100), not we know we can do this with a huge IF statement, but it would be easier to maintain if this could be done dynamically..

Regards

PeteA

Is there a way to dynamically build-up a string that references a control value?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a field you've named `first-name`, the best way to access it is to use `$first-name`. But you can also use:

```
fr:control-string-value('first-name')
```

This  allows you dynamically construct the name of the field, say with:

```
fr:control-string-value(concat('first', '-', 'name'))
```

See also the [doc for `fr:control-string-value()`](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-functions/extension-form-runner#fr-control-string-value).

Comment: To make it truly dynamic we would need to:
1. populate a variable
2. use that variable in the xPath string e.g. fr:control-string-value(concat('var1', '-', 'var2'))

Would this work too?
PeteA

Comment: @PeteAtkin I am not sure: could you tell us more about your actual use case?

Comment: So the issue is that if we copy a section (with its contents) to a new section then all the controls are copied as expected with a different suffix. But the formulae within the new controls all point to the original section, so these no longer work correctly.
So we wanted to create a dynamic formula that reads information from its current section, and to do this we need to know the current section/grid, and also a reference field name. Hence the need to dynamically build a control reference name.
We cannot use repeating grids due to a limitation on the way SAP passes data to the form.

Comment: @PeteAtkin OK, so let's assume that all the fields in your first section have a suffix `-a`, and all the fields in the second section have a suffix `-b`. So you could have a field named `first-name-a` in the first section and `first-name-b` in the section section. So you want to refer to the first name field from a section, and you want to write XPath that can be kept the same across sections. You could do: `let $suffix := tokenize(local-name(), '-')[last()] return fr:control-string-value(concat('first-name-', $suffix))`. You'll let me know if this works for you! -Alex

Comment: @PeteAtkin Did you get a chance to try the expression in my previous comment to access a "First name" field in the current section (whichever section it is, with the understanding that there are multiple such "first name" fields in the form)? -Alex